# Python: "No module named 'requests' " after pip3 install requests in pipenv

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

I'm trying to install the library requests in pipenv, with Python 3.  I've tried:

1. `pip install requests`, before forgetting that `pip` installs only for Python 2, leading to,
2. `pip3 install requests`, which returns assuringly

---

```
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.8,>=2.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests) (2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.24,>=1.21.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests) (1.23)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests) (2018.8.24)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)
```

When I run my python files with `import requests`, everything works, but when I run `pipenv run python mypythonscript.py`, I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'`. Please advise what I'm missing.

Comment: What version of Python is used by `pipenv run python`?

Comment: pipenv runs Python 3.7

Comment: And pip3? `pip3 --version`?

Comment: Try `pipenv run pip install requests`.  Otherwise you're installing `requests` to your user's `site-packages`, but you run your script in a `virtualenv` where packages are separate and `requests` isn't installed

Comment: @MikhailBurshteyn! You're a hero! Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that `pip3 install requests` runs outside of pipenv's virtualenv, it is installed outside of virtualenv, and thus `requests` library is not found from code running inside the virtualenv.

The correct way to install the library into the virtualenv is `pipenv install requests`, which will also add `requests` to your Pipfile.  If you want to install it temporarily without saving into the Pipfile, you can run `pipenv run pip install requests`.